# Binding ColorPicker in JavaFX to Label Background property

Tags: javafx, background, color-picker

Works well for foreground by simply:

```
    ObjectProperty op = label.textFillProperty();
    ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker(Color.GRAY);   
    ...             
    op.bind(cp.valueProperty());
```

How do I do it for Background - not even sure it is possible, due to the complexity of Background property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, don't use raw types. The code you posted should be

```
ObjectProperty<Paint> op = label.textFillProperty();
ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker(Color.GRAY);   
...             
op.bind(cp.valueProperty());
```

For the background you can use [`Bindings.createObjectBinding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createObjectBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-):

```
ObjectProperty<Background> background = label.backgroundProperty();
background.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    BackgroundFill fill = new BackgroundFill(cp.getValue(), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY);
    return new Background(fill);
}, cp.valueProperty());
```

Comment: Thanks James. I don't normally use raw types but here I have generic property editor for all controls and selected sets of properties  (Label example):

        ObservableMap<Object,Object> props = getProperties(); 
        props.put("Text", textProperty()) ...

... in a generic editor I have a popup around this list. Is this the right way (learning modern Java on porting of old code)

Comment: Not quite sure without context, and I guess it's off-topic for you question (that is my fault though...), but a `ObjectProperty<Paint>` is a subclass of `Object` just the same as `ObjectProperty` is. So it's not clear this would force you to use raw types (imo you should never use them).